# How to make git-diff disregards single-line matches?

Tags: git, diff

Most of the time, git diff produces reasonable outputs. However, when make large change to a block of text, by example, when replacing the whole body of a function, git diff will try and match empty lines and lines only containing a brace. This result in unreadable diff because old code and new code are interleaved in unreasonable way.

I'd like diff to not attempt to match single line if they are surrounded by changed line. How can it be done?

Comment: None of Git's diff alternatives do this. You can avoid *matching* on "noise" lines using the `patience` or `histogram` algorithms, which may help, but once the matching positions are chosen, Git may still show you the output in a form you dislike. Vampire's answer (or any other external diff method) may be the only option.

Comment: @torek Do you know an external diff that will do just that?

Comment: No. You could write a post-processing filter that uses the matches (and non-matches) that some existing diff found, in which case you would probably want patience or histogram style diffs. You might also want to read through Chapter 3 of [this nowhere-near-finished book](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `git difftool` instead and use a diff tool that presents the diff the way you like it.